# Dynamic Generated Folder Redirect to Php file in htaccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am generating a dynamic page on this dynamic "product" folder.

It is working fine  `category/product/heading-1`

---

when I am visiting only the  `category/product/` folder it shows me an error

`Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.`

```
#This file in the category folder
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)  product.php?u=&1 [NC,L]
```

how to redirect  `category/product/` to   `exmple.com/category/product.php`

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteRule ^product  product.php [NC,L]`? However, I usually recommend using a [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) pattern together with a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) instead of setting up all the URL rewrites on the web server. It also makes it much easier to move the application from one web server to another (like nginx that doesn't read htaccess files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Place your htaccess file inside category folder and make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also your url category/product doesn't have any further path so nothing to pass as query string, hence I have removed it from second rule in following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/([\w-]+)/?$  product.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/?$  product.php [NC,L]
```